# Removing Strings From a Variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am working on a batch file to loop through a list of strings (separated by commas) and remove them from the contents of a variable. However, I can't seem to get it working.

I was expecting for the varaible to have the strings removed from it, like so:

Lets say I have a list of `a,b,c` and I wanted to detect and remove those characters from a variable, for example, `set "var=abcd"`.

I want it to loop through the characters in the list and remove them from the variable:

```
set "var=%var:~a=%"
set "var=%var:~b=%"
set "var=%var:~c=%"
```

so the output would be:

```
> echo %var%
d

>
```

However, what I am getting is this using the code at the bottom:

```
> echo %var%
ECHO is off.

>
```

What is going on here?
(I am fairly new to batch and I could not find anything that would help me)

My code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo on
::Set the variable list, with '_' at the end to make the end of the items
set "varlist=a,b,c"
set varlist=%varlist%_
set "var="
set "string=acd"

::Loop through each character until ',' is found, then goto :var to remove it from the string
:loopvar
set ch=%varlist:~0,1%
set varlist=%varlist:~1%
if "%ch%"=="," goto var
set "var=%var%%ch%"
if "%varlist%"=="_" goto var
goto loopvar

::Remove from variable
:var
set "string=%string:~%var%=%"
set "var="
if "%varlist%"=="_" goto end
goto loopvar

::Display final result
:end
echo %var%
pause
```

Comment: If you're deliberately enabling delayed expansion, the least you could do is use it. Start by trying here ```set "string=%string:~%var%=%```, at the same time correcting the unbalanced quoting problem.

Comment: `set "var="` at the very end there unsets the variable, so there's nothing to display. Also `~` is only for length-based substrings, not substitution like you have in `set "string=%string:~%var%=%"`.

Comment: If you remove the string from `string` variable, then the final result is in `string` variable (_not_ in `var` variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm... This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Set the variable list, with ',' at the end to make the end of the items
set "varlist=a,b,c,"
set "string=acd"

set "p=%%"
set "var=%varlist:,=" & call set "string=!p!string:!var!=!p!" & set "var=%"

echo %string%
```

A detailed description of the method used appears at [this thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429). You can also remove the `@echo off` line and carefully review the executed code, so you can grasp *the magic*... **`;)`**

Comment: You're right! Thanks for the additional info :)